# Wamp Server - Redirect to an html file?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

What I'm trying to do is quite simple.

When I go to `localhost:8080`, I would like WampServer to redirect me to an html file somewhere in my www folder.

The idea here is that I don't want to have to type `localhost:8080/something/file.html` in order to get to the page I'm trying to get to.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You need to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects. Then you can use a dummy domain name like `project1.test` in the browser address bar. See the Dup for details of how to do that in WAMPServer

Comment: _Medium sized note_ You should never place anything in the `/wamp/www` folder, that is reserved for WAMPServer homepage etc

Comment: It is also better to stay with port 80, it makes life much simpler. If you had to move it because IIS was installed, its quite legal to uninstall or disable IIS